# Validation formula to allow only latin characters and numbers

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint2010. I need Validation formula to allow only latin characters and numbers a-z, A-Z, 0-9. Can you help me write this formula.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to realise this functionality by standard features (Formulas or Event Receivers). You can try to use some realized features like [this](http://spregexfield.codeplex.com/)